# Visually select two words in Vim

Tags: vimrc, normal-mode, visual-mode

Say I have a phrase
`is later found at` and what to delete a phrase `later found`, then what I do would be

In the normal mode, I put a cursor on `l`, and press `vww`. This will select from `l` to `a` of `at`.

This is not very practical for deleting and replacing phrases. Is there a better way/way to modify this behaviour such that
`vw` will select a word and a space after that and not the first letter of the next word?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Closest to your method

`v2e` to visually select to the `end` of the 2nd word. Therefore `v2ec` would
select the two words and then `change` them (i.e. delete them and leave you in
insert mode)

You can avoid visual mode altogether (saving a keystroke) and do `c2w` to 'change 2
words' (`c2e` would also work). Of course, you don't get any visual feedback,
so you need to get it right first time (which isn't too hard, once you get used
to it).

#### Or use text objects from visual mode (see `:help text-objects`)

Text objects are nice because you can repeat them using the dot command on
other places in the text as long as the cursor is somewhere on the text object
(e.g. a word, sentence, paragraph, between quotes, between parentheses...)

note the `h` to move back onto the end of the word...:

- `v2awhc` would change the two words
- `v2awhy` would yank the two words
- `v2awhd` would delete the two words
- `v2awhg~` would toggle the case of the two words

note the `3i` instead of the `h`...:

- `v3iwc` would change the two words
- `v3iwy` would yank the two words
- `v3iwd` would delete the two words
- `v3iwg~` would toggle the case of the two words

#### Or use text objects from normal mode (see `:help text-objects`)

- `c2aw` would change the two words
- `y2aw` would yank the two words
- `d2aw` would delete the two words
- `g~2aw` would toggle the case of the two words

Since text objects are nice, and since you can see they work better straight
from normal mode (compared to visual mode) I prefer to avoid visual mode most
of the time (but not all the time: visual mode is just the right thing in some
situations).

Comment: I think you have an extra d in the visual case-toggle mapping.

Comment: There’s also the difference between (_e.g._) `d2aw` and `2daw`, mostly in how they interact with `.`. I find `daw.` easiest, but I don’t like to count

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Thanks for pointing out the typo (fixed). And re the difference noticed it since I tend to just use `daw` + `.` until I've deleted all the words (I don't like counting either :) ). Anything requiring more than ~4 hits of the `.` will prompt me to use a different motion (`f`, `t, `/` etc.) in the first place

Comment: Thank you I guess `vee` works as equally well as the answer; and thank for mentioning other useful shortcuts!